# Convert IQueryable to DataRowView

Tags: c#, linq

I have a bindingsource which is bounded by an IQueryable result of LINQ to SQL.

```
private void loadProducts(short _engineID)
{    
     dbLinqDataContext db = new dbLinqDataContext();                   
     var  productQuery = from pe in db.productEngines
                         where pe.EngineID == _engineID
                         select new
                         {
                           ProductID = pe.ProductID,
                           ProductNumber = pe.product.ProductNumber,
                           Description = pe.product.ProductName,
                           Cost = String.Format("{0:C}", pe.product.StandardCost),
                           Price = String.Format("{0:C}", pe.product.ListPrice),
                           QOH = String.Format("{0:0.00}",pe.product.QOH),
                           Picture = pe.product.Picture,
                           Category =pe.product.category.Category1,   

                           Engine=pe.engine.ModelSeriesYear,
                           Manufacturer=pe.engine.manufacturer.Manufacturer
                        };
```

productQueryBindingSource.DataSource = productQuery;
    }

Then i am unable to convert my bindingsource current item to DataViewRow.

```
DataRow currentRow = ((DataRowView)productQueryBindingSource.Current).Row;
```

How can I cast my Anonymous Type to DataViewRow type?

Answer (score 0):

to convert the Anonymous to DataRow, should use the reflection. For more info check the below link

[Converting Custom Collections To and From DataTable](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting_Custom_Collections_To_and_From_DataTable.aspx)